# How to speed up Angular 4 Project

Tags: angular

I had worked on Angular 4 project, In which there are multiple modules(more then 15 in every component) and in each module there are multiple components. Whenever I reload the project all the files are loading at that time because of this the project is slow and it takes time to load.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question might be far to broad to be answered. Maybe you can add some information about how the build process, what "compiling" steps are used (minify, sass etc.) - and also how you work with it. Maybe you re-"compile" it all the time when you realod or don't "compile"/build at all. Also please develop and present some ideas or theories how it could be possible that your project is so slow and we can discuss them here.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608822/4399281

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Lazy Loading Feature Modules in angular?? Reference https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

Try **LazyLoading** it will solve your issue

- Lazy loading in Angular is about code. The build tool splits the build output into several files depending on the lazy loading configuration of the router.
- Only when components of a lazy loaded module are actually required because a route was selected that has to load such a component, this code file is finally loaded into the browser.
- The main benefit is that the initial load (time to first render) is shorter, and if there are parts of your application that are usually not needed by the user, less memory is required in the browser.

[LazyLoading Guide](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)