# How to apply gzip and minify the files in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I want to use zip method for my angular 6  project.

Main.ts itself is taking 2.92MB.

Questions:

1. How to apply the zip method(steps)??
2. How it works and what is the use of that??
3. Is this method help me for reducing the bundle size??
4. How the browser unzip the files??

Can anybody help me for this??

Actually, my project is taking 3 minutes for loading. And I read about zipping method, Is this method help me to solve my performance issue??

Comment: Did you try the production build?

Comment: The gzipping must be configured on the web server that you choose to deploy and serve your files. It consists in... gzipping the files, i.e. compressing them, so that less bytes need to be downloaded by the browser. It will make things slightly faster, especially on slow networks, but if your app takes 3 minutes to load, you have a serious problem somewhere.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608822/4399281

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about zipping but you should try AOT compilation.

`ng serve --aot`

Please refer https://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1450/angular-ahead-of-time-aot